# Use hardware key to secure RDP login

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop, windows-server

I would like to restrict access to our windows Servers using a hardware keys additionally to passwords.

Is it possibly to restrict connecting to (local) RDP to specific U2F Fido keys? And/or to restrict direct logon to servers so the user needs the U2F/Fido key, too?

Or are there other hardware like smart cards which could be used to restrict logon to computers?

Comment: Using Forefront Identity Manager and Active Directory, you can set up authentication via Smart Card or whatever. Don’t know about any details though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides technical details on Smart Card authentication.

> [Smart Card Technical Reference (Windows 10, Windows Server 2016) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-windows-smart-card-technical-reference)
>
> Smart cards are tamper-resistant portable storage devices that can
>   enhance the security of tasks such as authenticating clients, signing
>   code, securing e-mail, and **signing in with a Windows domain account**.

For a third-party, two-factor authentication solution, consider [Duo Security](https://duo.com/) which implements two-factor authentication for Windows using various authentication methods, including U2F.

> - [Duo Authentication for Windows Logon and RDP | Duo Security](https://duo.com/docs/rdp)
>    Duo integrates with Microsoft Windows client and
>     server operating systems to add two-factor authentication to Remote
>     Desktop and local logons.
> - [Authentication Methods | Duo Security](https://duo.com/product/trusted-users/two-factor-authentication/authentication-methods)
>   Authenticate anywhere, anytime, with any device using Duo Security’s options for
>     two-factor authentication methods: **U2F**, Phone Callback, HOTP & TOTP, Security Tokens, SMS Passcodes, Bypass Codes.

Also, consider other solutions quickly found online:

- SASSPASS - [Windows OS - Two-factor Authentication](https://saaspass.com/platforms/windows-os-two-factor-authentication-one-time-password/)
- AuthLite - [Affordable Two-Factor Authentication For Active Directory](https://www.authlite.com/)

Comment: Smart cards might be the way to go - but the technical reference is very abstract. Is there a good documentation how to use smart Cards somwhere?

Comment: No user guides how to roll out smart cards anywhere?